# what actually happens during a c- style typecasting regarding address space of casted objects?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

According to book, C++ FAQ by Cline,the following code depicts improper inheritance.
notice that i can add a banana which is a kind-of fruit into a bagofApples which should actually contain only apples.. but due to the inheritance relationship banana is added to the bagofApples.

but the question is what actually happens at this line:

```
 { return (Apple&) BagOfFruit::remove(); }//what does happen here?
```

what does the c-style type casting do here?
notice that the sizeof(banana) is 4004,while that of an apple is only 4.
so though the remove function of the banana object is accessed by the apple object because the apple's function's address offset would be matching with that of banana's,but when the banana is typecasted to an apple object what happens to the data member ar[1000] of the banana?
where does it lie in memory for the apple& reference here,what happens to the address space of the casted banana object(actual object)?

```
Apple& a2 = bagOfApple.remove();
```

The full code follows.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Fruit
{
    public:
    virtual void printClassName() const throw() = 0;
    virtual ~Fruit() throw();
};
Fruit::~Fruit() throw()
{ }

class Apple : public Fruit 
{
    public:
    virtual void printClassName() const throw();
};

void Apple::printClassName() const throw()
{ cout << "Apple\n"; }

class Banana : public Fruit 
{
    public:
    virtual void printClassName() const throw();
    protected:
        int ar[1000];
};

void Banana::printClassName() const throw()
{ cout << "Banana\n"; }
//The following BagOfFruit class allows insertion and removal of objects of any
//kind-of Fruit.
class Full { };
class Empty { };
class BagOfFruit 
{
    public:
    BagOfFruit() throw();
    unsigned size() const throw();
    void insert(Fruit& f) throw(Full);
    Fruit& remove() throw(Empty);
    protected:
    enum { maxSize_ = 20 };
    unsigned size_;
    Fruit* data_[maxSize_];
};

BagOfFruit::BagOfFruit() throw()
: size_(0)
{ }

unsigned BagOfFruit::size() const throw()
{ return size_; }

void BagOfFruit::insert(Fruit& f) throw(Full)
{
    if (size_ == maxSize_) throw Full();
    data_[size_++] = &f;
}

Fruit& BagOfFruit::remove() throw(Empty)
{
    if (size_ == 0) throw Empty();
    return *data_[--size_];
}


void insertFruitIntoBag(BagOfFruit& bag, Fruit& fruit)
{
bag.insert(fruit);
}

class BagOfApple : public BagOfFruit {
public:
BagOfApple() throw();
void insert(Apple& a) throw(Full);
Apple& remove() throw(Empty);
};

BagOfApple::BagOfApple() throw()
: BagOfFruit()
{ }

void BagOfApple::insert(Apple& a) throw(Full)
{ BagOfFruit::insert(a); }

Apple& BagOfApple::remove() throw(Empty)
{ return (Apple&) BagOfFruit::remove(); }//what does happen here?


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BagOfApple bagOfApple;
    Banana banana;
    insertFruitIntoBag(bagOfApple, banana);
    cout << "Removing an Apple from bagOfApple: ";
    Apple& a2 = bagOfApple.remove();
    a2.printClassName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth did you tag this as C? This isn't even remotely C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if this code comes from the book then get another book:

- I understand it illustrates a deliberate mistake in publicly deriving a BagOfApples from a BagOfFruit (which is nonsensical because public derivation means people can continue to use the BagOfApples *as* a BagOfFruit, thereby inserting objects into it that are not Apples) **BUT**
- It is riddled with other issue and poor design:

  - Ownership of fruit is never taken by the bag containers... they accept references to the objects then take their address.  By not having `insert()` take a pointer, they're falsely implying the object is copied by value.  This user interface is prone to application-crashing erroneous usage.
  - Stroustrup himself has said exception specifications have proven a mistake and shouldn't be used (I'll try to find a link to the interview transcript online if anyone's really intererested and can't find such themselves).
  - The `remove()` method is deceptive as it returns the value.  Comp Sci literature generally uses the term `pop()` for this.

> but the question is what actually happens at this line:

```
{ return (Apple&) BagOfFruit::remove(); }//what does happen here?
```

Well, `remove()` "pops" a fruit from the bag/container, and the C-style cast simply promises the compiler that that popped fruit is an `Apple`.  That's only likely to be correct if the bag is used exclusively through the BagOfApples-specific interface, but given it publicly derives from BagOfFruit it is entirely possible for some code to use it as a BagOfFruit and insert some other type of fruit into there.  If an `Apple&` is being returned but the object is not an `Apple`, and someone attempts to operate on the supposed `Apple`, then you'll have undefined behaviour.

In practice, this code will probably work as expected for most real-world compiler implementations.  But, let's say apple adds a "const char*" member to store the region where it's grown.  Lets say you go to print or compare the region but the object's really a `Banana`: the compiler's likely to reinterpret the bits with values for `ar[0]` and perhaps `ar[1]` (for 32 bit ints and 64 bit systems) as a `const char*`, then try to use the string at that non-sensical address.  This is very likely to cause a segmentation fault and crash your program.  But remember that even if that doesn't sound like it'd bite you with your exact usage, the behaviour's technically *undefined* and may be worse.

Comment: so can you suggest me a book that discusses the real aspects of programming language(C++) for e.g not books that only say that public inheritence make all public members to public,protected to protected and prive to private... but those that actually explain why this actually happens and what is its use in software development.Discussing practical aspects of software development.i got the reference of this book from c++ faqs http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ which is considered a good c++ faq resource.. is the book bad? see this book http://goo.gl/rI6uH

Comment: @ashishsony: Marshall Cline's FAQ answers (at the address you link) are very polished and rewarding reading - any professional programmer should be aquainted with all the issues and understand his answers, though you may not agree with all of them (e.g. I sometimes pass by pointer as a hint in calling code that they're accepted non-const - Marshall's FAQ recommends references). I've never seen anything from his book before... I can only guess that it doesn't get anywhere near the level of critical feedback enjoyed by the online FAQ, and therefore isn't as polished.

Comment: @ashishsony: and I must admit I've taken no interest in introductory/intermediate C++ programming books in the last decade or more, so I'm not a good person to ask. That said, I still consider Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language* to have very well judged content to prepare a professional programmer already up to speed with general programming concepts (e.g. a good C programmer who knows no C++).

Comment: Finally, there are a *lot* of S.O. questions about good books - worth doing a search.

Answer (score 4):

"what does the c-style type casting do here?": Lying.  Lie to the
compiler, and it will get you in the end.

The meaning of the C style cast depends on what the compiler knows at
the point it occurs.  If the compiler has seen the definition of
`Banana`, and knows that it inherits from `Fruit`, then it is
a `static_cast`; if the compiler knows nothing of the relationship
between the two, it is a `reinterpret_cast`.  In both cases, using the
results (assuming that the actual type was `Apple`) is undefined
behavior.  When you explicitly cast, the compiler assumes you know what
you are doing—it takes the address of the object, and treats the
memory at that address as if it were a `Banana`.  If it actually is
a `Banana`, everything works fine; if it isn't, you've lied to the
compiler, and it's going to come back and haunt you.  The different size
is just an obvious example—if you write to something beyond the
end of `Apple`, you're going to overwrite memory that doesn't belong to
the object, or possibly trigger an access violation.  But even if
`Apple` and `Banana` have the same size, you're in undefined behavior
land, and pretty much anything could happen.

Answer (score 1):

> what does the c-style type casting do
>   here?

It does nothing. I mean, you are only change the reference type to your concrete object. If you do a wrong cast, there will be some problems (even if the compiler doesn't complain about it).
You should avoid c-style cast in C++. If you want to cast a base object reference to a derived class reference, you need to inspect the type at runtime. Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/). It's a good tutorial.

> so though the remove function of the banana object is accessed by the apple object because the apple's function's address offset would be matching with that of banana's

No.

> where does it lie in memory for the apple& reference here,what happens to the address space of the casted banana object(actual object)?

Nothing. Casts don't change anything in this case because it's a cast to a reference type, so it creates a reference. . They just tell the compiler to not complain about types. If you need a c-style cast in C++ you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: *This* cast doesn't "change" anything, because it's a cast to a reference type, so it creates a reference. A cast like `(float)4` creates a temporary float object with value 4.0, which is more than just "telling the compiler not to complain about types", since it doesn't have the same bit pattern as the integer 4. A cast from derived class pointer to base class pointer in a multiple-inheritance hierarchy commonly results in a different address, which is rather important :-)

Comment: As an aside: there are some cases where you can safely downcast with `static_cast` (because you somehow *know* the object is of the derived type), and you want to avoid `dynamic_cast` because your source type has no virtual functions. It comes up from time to time in generic programming. But this `Fruit` class does have virtual functions, so `dynamic_cast` is available, and there are no templates in sight. A `dynamic_cast` would catch the problem at the point the `Banana` is read out of the `BagOfApples`, although too late to save the sensible class invariant ("it's full of apples").

Comment: @Steve Jessop: yes.. thanks for adding value to the discussion.